# Can't gain access to local SQL for modification

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, iis

I've been given a backup of a production SQL database to begin writing an application against.
I've got it running as a local instance and using Windows Authentication and I can READ the information, however I cannot figure out how to get IIS to use my Windows Authentication to log into the SQL server when running a local ASP.Net website.

I don't have the authority on the DB to add users, and I'm getting an error of `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE'.` when I try to access a page that reads the database.

I don't think I will be able to communicate with the DB admin for a while to get him to fix this up for me.  Is there anything I can do here?

Comment: Getting IIS to use **your** credentials is a hard problem.  I'd recommend you use a username/password in your connection string.  If you'd like to try the hard way, search the web for "iis sql-server kerberos delegation".

Comment: @Andomar : I WANT to use a username/password definitely....but I don't have the authority to add one to the database for some reason.  :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your asp code is using the same identity that IIS runs under - the Network Service account.  To get it to use your credentials, you can either hard-code them into a connection string or you can use impersonation (see this link:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa292118%28VS.71%29.aspx)

The gist of the link:
Put this in your web.config file:  `<identity impersonate="true" />`

-t.

Comment: Just "-t."?  Where does that go in web.config exactly?

Comment: That's the second time I've seen the phrase "put this in your web.config" in reference to this issue and both times it was followed by blank text....I'm guessing there is a formatting problem?

Comment: @james Yeah, the texteditor strips out xml-like formatting unless its formatted as code (you can normally check by looking at the raw source of the post). Also, I'm pretty sure the '-t.' is just for his name lol

Comment: This leads me to now having the error: Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\IUSR'.

Comment: Alright, I got it working after adding that step, then I had to go to the SQL Instance and add 'NT AUTHORITY\IUSR' to the Logins THEN go to the specific Database and add it to the Users of that db.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an account in SQL Server for the Network Service account,ex via SSMS via the "Security" section, right click on "Logins" and select add. You will be adding a Windows Account, you can then lookup and validate the name "NETWORK SERVICE". Then switch to the "User Mapping" section and grant permission to view your database.

reference : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998320.aspx#paght000015%5Fsqlserver

2nd  Alternative 
If "integrated security=sspi" is there in your connection string than you should:

1. Turn on integrated auth in IIS
2. Turn on windows auth in asp.net
3. Turn on imerposation in asp.net

Hopefully it will help.